# How to secure AJAX call with Django backend?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I want to secure my django view from responding to someone who isn't logged in to my app.
I use AJAX to get data, but I can also get that for example by Postman what is unwanted.

I'm doing POST request and I'm checking if CSRF token is set, but it isn't good enough secure.
What can I do and how?

PS. I read some articles before, but every where I looked was too complex. If I can, please explain that in the easiest way possible. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the view that's returning the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add the [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator to your view. For a function based view:

```
@login_required
def your_view(request):
   ...
```

Comment: Yes, to Django there is no difference apart from a couple of headers. The session cookie will be sent with the request so you can check if the user is logged in